# How to Change Color  selected Picked value from pickerview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview

```
pickerArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"20", @"40", @"60",@"80", @"100", @"120", @"140", @"160", @"180", @"200",nil] retain];

 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        //On Selecting the component row
        if (component == 0) {

        } else if (component == 1) {

            [quantityPickerDelegate didChangeLabelText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];// delegate passing the selected value
             pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0745 green:0.357 blue:1.0 alpha:1];

    }   


- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    //Picker view content added
    pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    pickerLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    if (component == 0)
    {
        [pickerLabel setText:@"Total"];
        pickerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 200,220,44);
        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0745 green:0.357 blue:1.0 alpha:1];
    }

    else
    {
        pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        pickerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 200,70,44);
        [pickerLabel setText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    pickerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20];
    pickerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];

    //return [pickerLabel autorelease];

    return pickerLabel;
}
```

I am trying to change the selected Picked Value Color from `UIPickerView`

I am trying to change it but its not effected perfectly its changing other values below the selected value.

Comment: pickerLabel is UILabel used in viewForRow delegate method.

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect. You should reload the selected component. Then you need to fetch the selected row and update its color in `viewForRow:forComponent:`. Something like-

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        //On Selecting the component row
        if (component == 0) {

        } else if (component == 1) {

            [quantityPickerDelegate didChangeLabelText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];// delegate passing the selected value
            [pickerView reloadComponent:component]; //This will cause your viewForComp to hit
        }
    }

- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     //...
     //Your usual code
      pickerLabel.textColor = defaultColor;

     if([self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) //this is the selected one, change its color
     {
            pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0745 green:0.357 blue:1.0 alpha:1];
     } 
}
```