# UIPickerView Selected Row Label Color

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I've made a custom UIPickerView but I'd like the UILabel to change color when scrolled into the selected row like this;

[image: UIPickerView]

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
What I'd like to do is change the color of the UILabel *whilst the selection is being made*, i.e. whilst the wheel is turning, not afterwards.

Here's what I've got so far, which changes the color of the UILabel after you have made a selection:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    AILabel * pickerRow = view ? (AILabel *)view:[[[AILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 40)] autorelease];
    pickerRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    pickerRow.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    pickerRow.insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);

    if(component == 0)
    {
        pickerRow.text = [self.numberArray objectAtIndex:row];
        if ( row == number )
        {
            pickerRow.alpha = 0.0f;
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.33f
                                  delay: 0.0f
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 pickerRow.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                 pickerRow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                 pickerRow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
                                 pickerRow.alpha = 1.0f;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             }];
        }
        else
        {
            pickerRow.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            pickerRow.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            pickerRow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pickerRow.text = [self.durationArray objectAtIndex:row];
        if ( row == duration )
        {
            pickerRow.alpha = 0.0f;
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.33f
                                  delay: 0.0f
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 pickerRow.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                 pickerRow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                 pickerRow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
                                 pickerRow.alpha = 1.0f;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             }];
        }
        else
        {
            pickerRow.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            pickerRow.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            pickerRow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    return pickerRow;
}
```

The AILabel is just a custom UILabel, nothing special about it.
The 'number' variable is the current selected value in the first component.
The 'duration' variable is the current selected value in the second component.

Hope this is clearer

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595220/how-to-change-color-selected-picked-value-from-pickerview

Comment: Whithout any code it's complicated to help you...

Comment: paste your code so that we can help you

Comment: i've updated the question and included code.  don't think i made it clear enough what i wanted

Answer (score -1):

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel*) view;
        if (label == nil) {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        }

        label.textColor  = [UIColor RedColor];
        CGSize rowSize = [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component];
        CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake (0, 0, rowSize.width, rowSize.height);
        [label setFrame:labelRect];

        return label;
    }



- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 UILabel *selectedRow = (UILabel *)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
        selectedRow.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```